# Moment generating functions question

Tags: probability, self-study, moment-generating-function

> Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent, where each $X_i$ has probability (mass) function $p_i(x_i)$ given as $p_i(x_i) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda_i^{x_i}}{x_i!}$ (only the parameter $\lambda_i$ differs int he distribution of each $X_i$ for $x_i = 0, 1, ...$. What is the distribution of their sum: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ ? Prove it (perhaps with moment generating functions).

Answer: The moment generating function of Poisson (sum of $\lambda$)

I don't get how to do this question and I don't really understand the question. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be start with 2, then n. What is the sum of two independent poisson random variables?

Comment: I still don't get it.. Isn't the sum of the two independent poisson random variables the product of its moment generating functions?

Comment: No, the *MGF of the distribution of the sum* is the product of the MGFs. The MGF of the Poisson is simple. If you have trouble, you might like to let $a = (e^t - 1)$ and see how you go, then put $e^t-1$ back in for $a$ at the end.

Comment: @Sue, Through valid MGF (moment generating function) one can uniquely identify the random variable. follow Glen's correction.

Comment: Well, I tried it and got $e^{\lambda(e^t -1)}$ as the answer. What do I do next?

Comment: I was just wondering, what is the difference between finding the MGF for $X_i$ and the distribution of their sum?

Comment: @Sue, I suggest you to spend some time with MGF. Understand the properties MGF and relationship of random variable and its MGF.    wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function may be helpful.

Comment: Sue, the two most useful facts about MGF are:
1. MGF of the sum of independent random variables is the product of their respective MGFs
2. MGF uniquely identifies the distribution.

Equiped with this two facts, and your calculation of MGF of Poisson Variable (which is correct) you should be able to finish this problem. But similarly to vinux I recommend you try to understand MGFs some more, especially the two properties I mentioned.

Comment: The issue here is that the **Answer** given to Sue is not an answer to the question she has been asked: What is the _distribution_ of their sum: $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$? The correct answer to the question that she has been asked is that the sum has a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$ and _not_ **The moment generating function of Poisson(sum of** $\lambda$ **)**; that is the answer to a different question: What is the MGF of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$?

Answer (score 4):

The MGF is $\psi_{X_i}(t)=e^{\lambda_i(e^t-1)}$. The MGF of $S_n$, $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is $\psi_{S_n}(t)=\prod_{i=1}^n \psi_{X_i}(t)$. So what we get is

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n \psi_{X_i}(t)=\prod_{i=1}^ne^{\lambda_i(e^t-1)}=e^{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(e^t-1)}=e^{\lambda^*(e^t-1)}
$$
where $\lambda^*=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i$. Since the result is the MGF of a Poisson with parameter $\lambda^*$, the conclusion is that the sum of independent Poisson random variables with different parameters is a Poisson random variable with the sum of their individual parameters as its parameter.

Edit: If it wasn't clear enough, the conclusion is this:

$$
\text{If }X_i \text{ are independently distributed, } X_i\sim Po(\lambda_i), \, i=1, \dots, n\\
\text{then } \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=S_n \sim Po\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\right).
$$
A special case of this relation is very often used, namely when the $X_i$ are not only independently but also identically distributed. In that case, $S_n$ is $Po(n\lambda)$. As initially shown, this is quite easily shown using moment generating functions.